# JPA query on bean field from collection

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have next class relations :

```
public class Company {
  . . .
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Set<CompanySecUser> companySecUsers;
  . . .
}
public class CompanySecUser{
    . . .
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User secUser;

    @Column(name = "IS_READ")
    private BigDecimal isRead;
    . . .
}
```

Now how to write query in JPA on Company entity to get only companies with specified secUser.id and isRead = 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select company from Company company 
    join company.companySecUsers user 
    where user.id = <ID> and user.isRead = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Company> list = session.createQuery("from Company company where company.companySecUsers.isRead=:isRead").setParameter("isRead",1).list();
```