# Selecting from a list using JPA Query

Tags: java, jpa

I am very new to JPA and have the following entities defined

```
public class CustomerOrders {
  @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
  private Long customerId;
  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
  private List<Order> orders;
}

public class Order {
  @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
  private Long orderId;
  @Column(name = "AMOUNT", precision = 16, scale = 2, nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal orderAmount;
  @Column(name ="AWARD_FULFILLED_INDIC", nullable = false)
  private Boolean awardFulIndicator;
}
```

Given the above, how would I write a JPA query against the CustomerOrders entity, that when passed the customer id as a parameter, it would return those CustomerOrders having at least one Order with an amount of greater than $10 positive amount and whose AWARD_FULFILLED_INDIC is true?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I like this site http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL

Comment: @Leo thank you for that. But my problem is how do I iterate over the list of Orders and see if there is one that matches the criteria?

Comment: why don't you start from Order instead of CustomOrders? ;-)

Comment: @Leo , I did consider that - so after I get a list of Orders matching the criteria, wouldn't it be too taxing to then query the CustomerOrders table for those particular Ids?

Comment: Making the relationship bidirectional is a big problem in this case?

Comment: @Leo unfortunately it is. Hence my original problem :(

Comment: please check if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096848/jpa-query-on-bean-field-from-collection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerOrders c INNER JOIN c.orders o 
WHERE c.customerId = :cId AND o.awardFulIndic = true 
HAVING MAX(o.orderAmount) >= 10.00;
```

Comment: Thank you Leo and @MawrCoffeePls. I will give this a shot and keep you posted

Comment: would I need the "HAVING MAX" ? Couldn't I just do
`SELECT * FROM CustomerOrders c INNER JOIN c.orders o 
WHERE c.customerId = :cId AND o.awardFulIndic = true and o.orderAmount >= 10.00;` ?

Comment: @Leo and MawrCoffeePls thank you very much for your answers.This helped my issue!

Comment: If you didn't use the HAVING clause, you'd only get back the orders that themselves are over 10 dollars. If you want all orders that are part of a customer order that has at least one order of value greater than 10, use the HAVING MAX part.

Answer (score 0):

@MawrCoffeePls 's solution worked